# How do I stop the user from inputting a year before 1582 (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was assigned to make a leap year calculator and as far as I can tell it is working well, however, the user is still able to input a date before 1582. I am not sure how I would go about setting a limit on the entered date. Any help is much appreciated, thank you !!

Here is my program:

```
#intro
print("Hello and welcome to the greatest leap year calculator!")
print("This calculator goes all the way back to 1582, when the Gregorian Calendar was implemented!")

#user input
a= int(input("Please enter a year to see if it was a leap year: "))

#calculate leap years
def leapyr(a):
    if a % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if a % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if a % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False
print (leapyr(a))

#stop program from closing
input("Press enter to close: ")
```

Comment: simple `if` will get the job done like this `if a <= 1582: print('Invalid Input') ;a = int(input("Enter again");else: leapyr(a);`

Comment: how about adding a loop? `while  a<=1582: a= int(input("Please enter year after 1582: "))`

Comment: Just to note, leap years existed before 1582; it's just that 1300, 1400, etc were all leap years as well. The result was too many days being added over the course of 1500 years or so, so the Gregorian calendar "reset" the year to bring it back into sync and to eliminate some leap years in the future.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as the assignment was explained, but I believe that is why my professor said to start at 1582; just to keep it somewhat simplified haha

Comment: @p.adams, you should accept one answer to close the question. Happy you solved your problem.

Comment: I was just about to do that. I am used to Reddit so I was trying to upvote haha. How would one go about doing that? (sorry I am super new to this site) edit: Figured it out XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    a = int(input("Please enter a year to see if it was a leap year: "))
    if a > 1582:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

If you want, you can add exception handling:

```
try:
    a = int(input("Please enter a year to see if it was a leap year: "))
except TypeError:
    print("Insert an integer value")
except BaseError:
    continue
```

Comment: @sittsering, fixed, writing directly into the white space is a bit difficult, I always made some mistakes. Thank you

Comment: i think else block is not needed in this case, if condition is false, it'll iterate anyways.

Comment: @sittsering, it's only a PEP rule, to make the code cleaner. But if you want the code to appear shorter, you can surely do like you said

Answer (score 2):

Loop until you are "happy" with the input

```
print("Hello and welcome to the greatest leap year calculator!")
print("This calculator goes all the way back to 1582, when the Gregorian Calendar was implemented!")


def is_year_valid(year):
    try:
        value = int(year)
        if value < 1582:
            return False, None
        else:
            return True, value
    except ValueError:
        return False, None

def leapyr(a):
    if a % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if a % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if a % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False


valid = False
while not valid:
    valid, year = is_year_valid(input("Please enter a year to see if it was a leap year: "))


print(leapyr(year))

input("Press enter to close: ")
```